# Ingress file for Angular+Springboot application

Tags: angular, spring-boot, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have an Angular + Spring boot microservices application where there are about 10 backend microservices. Its a pretty big application with more than may be 100 REST end points.
We are thinking to move to on prem kubernetes. I wonder how do I define the ingress file, do I need to define all of the application REST end points in my spring application in ingress also?
I checked a couple of examples and I could see they use ingress as kind of Spring API gateway. Is that the correct architecture? Could anyone point me to a proper example?

Answer (score 1):

Mostly it depends on your requirement, what you are trying to use.

If you are just planning to use the **Nginx** ingress with your sprint boot you can simply use the **Nginx ingress controller** and set the **ingress**.

While if you have requirements of **API gateway** features like reate limiting, API key, basic auth, and others you need to use the API gateway like Kong and all.

> about 10 backend microservices. Its a pretty big application with more
> than may be 100 REST end points.

you can create the **1 ingresses** for **each microservice** with different **domain** routing or else with different **path-based** routing.

**Sub-Domain** based routing

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  rules:
    - host: service-1.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: service-1
              servicePort: 9000
            path: /(.*)
    - host: service-2.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: service-2
              servicePort: 8000
            path: /(.*)
    - host: service-3.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: service-3
              servicePort: 8000
            path: /(.*)
```

**Path** based routing with single domain `api.example.com`

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minimal-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  -  host: api.example.com 
     http:
      paths:
      - path: /service-1
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: service-1
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /service-2
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: service-2
            port:
              number: 80
```

So domain one will route your request to service when any request goes to that specific service.

```
service-2.example.com ---> service-2 
service-3.example.com ---> service-3
```

While in **path-based** Nginx will redirect requests based on path prefix in URL

```
api.example.com/service-2/* ---> service-2
```